# OAuth configuration is invalid due to wrong redirect URL

Tags: qgis

We are trying to configure our API URL in QGIS , which is OAuth protected. But when using OAuth 2 authentication mechanism in the tool, there is no option to modify the redirect URL . It is pointing to the local host, could you please help with same if we can do any workaround for the same or this can be updated?

[image: QGIS Image]